# sublime text 3 complete vim support

Tags: linux, vim, sublimetext3

I installed Vintageous in sublime text 3 so i can use some of vim commands and interactions. But I am using it for a long time, and there is a lot of features missing, like the 'ctrl+x' and 'ctrl+a" to decrease and increase a number, the 'ctrl+r' to redo, the 'ctrl+v' to select vertical blocks, 'ctrl+c' to quit insertion mode ... etc.

I really like sublime text 3, but in the other hand, i'm really missing this commands, it's all of theses commands which makes vim so powerful.

So how can I get a complete vim mode in sublime text 3. It would be just perfect if i can do that (because I really miss vim complete features).

PS : I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 with Linux version > 4.

Comment: Since none of us can make that happen for you, I strongly suggest you [file an issue](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous/issues) at the package's Github repo. I'm only somewhat familiar with the package, but some of the operations you mention are already available under other key combinations. You can always make new [custom key bindings](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html).

Comment: The package has a setting `vintageous_use_ctrl_keys`, which should solve most of your issues. If some commands are missing you can look for other packages and create a keybinding on your own.

Comment: @r-stein Thanks a looooooooooooooooooooot bro, you are a saver, please put your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vintageous has the setting `vintageous_use_ctrl_keys`, which should solve most of your issues.In contrast to other packages Vintageous uses the User preferences. Hence you can just add the entry `"vintageous_use_ctrl_keys": false` to "Preferences >> Settings - User". However for this settings there is an entry in the control palette. Press `ctrl+shift+p` and write `Vintageous: Toggle Vim Ctrl Keys`. You can see the other settings [here](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous/blob/master/Preferences.sublime-settings) and just change them in the user preferences.

If you are still missing some keys I would recommend to look at the default keymap and search for other packages, which provide this behavior and change the keybinding as you want them.

Comment: please, can you be more explicit about when to put this setting, so the persons who will read this can understand how to configure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Now there is a new player, [ActualVim](https://github.com/lunixbochs/ActualVim) plugin.

> Everything you like about using Sublime Text 3, and everything you
>   like about typing in vim.
>
> Actual uses an embedded [Neovim](https://neovim.io/) instance to accurately manipulate each
>   Sublime Text buffer as though you were editing the text directly in
>   vim, without breaking any Sublime Text features (aside from multiple
>   selection for now).

It’s way better than Vintage mode or Vintageous. You can use your own .vimrc, plugins, real vim motions and commands.

Comment: One annoyance that I couldn't find a solution for is tab navigation in ActualVim. I like using `gt`/`gT` to navigate between open tabs, but it doesn't work with ActualVim. And the project has no issue tracker so I have no idea if it's possible.

For that reason I switched to https://packagecontrol.io/packages/NeoVintageous

Answer (score 0):

### To get vim shortcuts in Sublime Text

1. Install [neovim](https://neovim.io/) (the actual program which is unrelated to sublime text - it's necessary for this approach to work). Example [`brew install neovim`](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/kbwhq9/whats_the_prefered_method_for_installing_neovim/).
2. In sublime, press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, type "install package" and click on the top result.
3. Now search for '[ActualVim](https://github.com/lunixbochs/ActualVim)', and click on it, it should install.
4. Close and reopen sublime.
5. Vim shortcuts now work!

Comment: The ActualVim repo seems dead.

Comment: @Breno good observation (no update since 2018). Even so it seemed to work just fine for me (I’m still using the above method on two laptops)